# "How to write benchmark" as a duplicate reason for question involving poor benchmark

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I personally stick with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), but probably the problem appears for other languages as well. There's a family of questions like this with some variations:

> I compared the speed of A approach and B approach and it turns out that B is significantly slower than A. Should we stop using B?

Then the benchmarking code follows which has serious methodological problems, so the benchmarking results are actually irrelevant. Often such questions are closed as duplicates of [How to write a correct microbenchmark in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) question. Examples:

- [Accessing instance field takes longer than declaring local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403771/accessing-instance-field-takes-longer-than-declaring-local-variables)
- [Leetcode Two Sum III - Data structure design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231725/leetcode-two-sum-iii-data-structure-design)
- [Does java 8 streams reuse itself when processed again on the same data and task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573687/does-java-8-streams-reuse-itself-when-processed-again-on-the-same-data-and-task)
- [Java 8 - External Iteration performing better than Internal Iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585795/java-8-external-iteration-performing-better-than-internal-iteration)

My opinion is that it's completely irrelevant. While it's sometimes ok to downvote such question as poorly researched and mention in comments that benchmarking is incorrect, they are not duplicates as OP asks something completely different. In some cases the OP results still hold even after rewriting the benchmark (and may discover really interesting effects - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462514/why-indirect-increment-is-faster-than-direct-inc) question). Even if OPs benchmark is actually poor, it would be much better to write good benchmark and discuss its results as an answer. Writing good benchmark is not trivial even after reading the canonical how-to-write-benchmark-quuestion, so it worth helping OP to solve the problem in his particular case. After all, many askers on this site cannot sort numbers or read command line arguments and they questions are still answered.

What do you think? Should we close questions involving poor benchmark (but not asking how to write benchmark) as duplicates of how-to-write-benchmark question?

Comment: If the dupe isn't directly answering the question, then *no*, I'd say that they're poor closures.  While the big flaw *is* the microbenchmark, the crux of those questions aren't to figure out how to write the benchmark.

Comment: While I'm not sure the fact that many askers lack basic computer skills is a good reason to continue to help them with programming problems, I think you're right about the duplicate not being a duplicate in this case. :)